# Where could I get waveform data on low-frequency earthquakes, very low-frequency earthquakes, volcanic tremor and non-volcanic earthquakes?

Tags: geophysics, earthquakes, seismology

I am a marine geology masters student and I am writing my thesis on slow earthquakes. I will include  graphs of the most common types of earthquakes:

- Low-frequency earthquakes
- Very low-frequency earthquakes
- Volcanic tremors
- Non-volcanic earthquakes

Does anyone know where I could get data? If anyone shares with me the above data, I will cite you in my acknowledgement section. Thanks :)

Comment: As @nate points out IRIS can be the place to go. You can use obspy to query waveforms, e.g.:

https://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.clients.fdsn.client.Client.get_waveforms.html

You might consider using a catalog of tremors to identify when/where to query the catalog. This resource comes to mind:

http://www-solid.eps.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~sloweq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one source I can think of that's outstanding with meeting all your enumerated criteria is the following: [IRIS](https://www.iris.edu/hq/).

You need to research throughout that website, but they certainly have more than what you seek